# Can't use response.json() on received user object from MS Graph

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a user from the MS Graph API.

```
export const getUser = async (id) => {
    //Gives me the token
    const token = await getToken(["User.Read", "User.ReadWrite"])
    //Appends to headers
    const headers = getHeaders(token)
    
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };
    return fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${id}`, options)
}

getUser("MYID").then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
    debugger
}).catch((error) => {
    debugger
})
```

Normally I can use .json() to resolve promises from MS Graph, but this call fails with the following error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

If I remove `.json()` I can read the response, which gives me the following:

```
response: Response
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
```

Given the fact that the body object should be of type ReadableStream, my intuition tells me that I in fact should be able to resolve the promise with `.json()`, i.e. `response.body.json()`. However, when I try to do so, I get the following error:

> TypeError: response.body.json is not a function at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4679:40

I'm pretty unsure what's going on, and naturally I would love if you guys could give me some insights on what's going on. All my other graph "GET" calls encounter no problem when I want to resolve the readableStream.

Comment: Because this is not a json, this is readable stream. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting response body as html or xml which is why .json() which is used to parse the data to json is throwing exception **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**